# When using the 'dd' command, are there any issues w/ "mounting" an empty, encrypted "destination hdd", such as potential data not making it onto hdd?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, mount

**PURPOSE**: determine if there are any negative risks associated with mounting a blank, encrypted, destination hdd, when using the following dd command:

```
(sudo dd if=/dev/sdx bs=16M of=/dev/mapper/diskname)
```

I was told in another post that mounting a hdd when using the 'dd' command can lead to multiple problems, such as, 1, potentially overwriting "deleted" data during the dd process. This could be problematic if the point of using the 'dd' command is to recover data that was accidentally deleted.

My **guess** is that mounting the "host" hdd could be problematic in numerous ways, as written above, but am "guessing" that mounting an encrypted, data-empty hdd, that is the "destination" hdd, would be harmless. But maybe this is not correct = why I am asking.

**UPDATE**: 
The encrypted hdd had the data copied to it, the encryption is intact, and it does open using the 'cryptsetup' command.......... BUT it won't mount! Mounting error: "bad fs type, bad superblock on x, bad option, etc...". Tried mounting it to other directories, like media, but same result.

```
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdx boo.boo
sudo mount /dev/mapper/boo.boo /mnt
```

Comment: Hmm? I find your question a bit unclear, what is it that you fear? Using a disk while dd is writing to it? (<-unlikely to be "useful" IMO). If you have a full copy of an already mounted disk and attempt to mount that copy while still having the original mounted - the duplicate ID's might possibly cause problems (same ID on two disks, never tried that).

Comment: Well, my fear is that if I mount the destination hdd, that after the duplication process is over, the destination hdd will have some sort of problem. For example, the hdd won't mount. Ironically, now, the hdd won't mount.

Comment: In general, the only consequences you should have had is exactly duplicate IDs. Was an origin HDD unmountend and closed in cryptsetup during a whole dd run?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I think you should read the answer below.

Comment: It seems I asked simultaneously with that answer. Yes, I am talking about the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accessing something via filesystem *and* via raw blocks *at the same time* is a very bad idea.

- using a `mount`ed disk/partition means: accessing the disk/partition **via file system** operations only, that is: creating/writing/reading files.
- Using `dd` with a disk/partition as a target means: writing/reading raw blocks. This is usually incompatible with accessing the same device at the same time via a different method.
- (Using `dd` with a file as a targets would mean reading from/writing to a file, mounting would be prerequisite then, and `dd` operations cannot clash with file system operations in that case.)

So if you **both** mount a disk/partition and write to it with `dd`, you might end up with an undesired result, because

- `dd` might overwrite critical file system structure (such as directory structure or arbitrary files), rendering the target unmountable for future operations,
- file system operations (say, flushing caches) might overwrite blocks already assigned to files (e.g. cache flush), which were recently used by `dd`, thus rendering your `dd` block copy inconsistent.

In either case, you might end up with inconsistent data, unless your `dd` and file system operations happen to use a different set of blocks by chance - which sounds impossible to guarantee.

Comment: at jvb. Thank you, well-explained. I learned a few new things today.

Comment: Please note that not only mounting, but having it open in cryptsetup, participating in RAID or LVM or in some kind of caching (bcache, flashcache) also in general impedes usage of dd. You have to cease absolutely any upper level activity of the device before accessing it directly with dd.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Good to know, thank you!

Comment: at jvb (or anyone)... "So if you both mount a disk/partition and write to it with dd, you might end up with an undesired result" : The host partition was not mounted, only the destination, so "both mounted" would not apply here. As much as I won't do it in the future, I'm wondering if the process of (only) mounting the empty destination hdd was problematic. Thx.

Comment: @topencrypt To clarify - I meant "both" (a) mounting destination partitions file system and (b) writing to the block device containing the file system with `dd` while the destination is mounted. The partition *isn't empty anymore* when there is a filesystem on it. While it is mounted, the operating system might decide to write to undisclosed locations on it at any time (cached things, access times, internal housekeeping info, even an "correctly unmounted" stamp later when unmounting it), thus ruining your `dd` copy.

Comment: @jvb Thanks for the clarification - appreciate it! So the bottom line is whether or not the destination hdd is technically empty, if it is mounted, the OS on the computer (not the host hdd) could possibly write to it and I would no longer have a duplicate of the host hdd. Thanks for your help!!